# React Navigation TabNavigator Swipe to StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I currently have the following Navigators:

```
const AppStack = StackNavigator({ Home: HomeScreen })

const AuthStack = StackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen })

export default SwitchNavigator(
  {
    Intro: IntroScreen,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    mode: 'modal',
    initialRouteName: 'Intro'
  }
)
```

where `IntroScreen` is a `TabNavigator` with swipe enabled.

How would I transition from the `IntroScreen` to `HomeScreen` once a user swipes past the last screen of the `TabNavigator`?

Currently `TabNavigator` does not allow you to swipe past the last screen

Comment: In the `SwitchNavigator`, if we put `App: AppStack,` before  `Intro: IntroScreen`, can we try if it works.

Comment: How would that work? I mean technically it shouldn't even make a difference.